# Receivers in handler functions such as filepath.WalkFunc

Tags: go

I've run into a small issue for which I have a bit of an ugly solution only.
I cannot imagine I'm the first, but I haven't found any clues on SO.

In the following (deliberately simplified) example I'd like to have a
receiver on the `walk` function which is my `filepath.WalkFunc`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

type myType bool

func main() {
    var t myType = true

    // would have loved to do something as:
    // _ = filepath.Walk(".", t.walk) 

    // that does not work, use a closure instead    
    handler := func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {return t.walk(path, info, err)}
    _ = filepath.Walk(".", handler)
}

func (t myType) walk(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {

    // do some heavy stuff on t and paths
    fmt.Println(t, path)

    return err
}
```

Func `main()` triggers `walk()` and because of the receiver `t` to `walk()`, I
cannot find another way than to use this ugly closure `handler` as an argument
to `filepath.Walk()`.  I would have hoped for something more like
`fileWalk(".", t.walk)` but that does not work.  It gives the compile error
" method t.walk is not an expression, must be called"

Is my closure solution the correct approach in this respect, or are there better options I don't know of.

PS.  This is one of several occasions in which I have to use this closure construction
to pass a handler function which has a receiver.  So, this question is more related
to passing handler functions than to `filepath` behaviour.

Thanks for you suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.

In Go, methods are mostly syntactic sugar, the receiver is actually the first parameter of the function. myType.walk basically has the signature `func(myType, string, os.FileInfo, error) error`. You can see this when you try to pass myType.walk into filepath.Walk instead of t.walk.

Comment: Do you mean, "there are no better alternatives than the closure method", or, "it is not possible to do this at all"? The example above compiles and runs, from which I conclude that the closure method works (even though it is a bit ugly).

Comment: OK, I see.  The compiler error illustrates your point.  I'll use the closure construct.  The function myType.Walk has 4 parameters instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

While you mention ignoring the behavior of filepath for the question, the examples given are largely dependent on it.

First, to address passing in a method, instead try defining an interface.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo interface {
    Bar(a string)
}

type myFoo bool

func (b myFoo) Bar(a string) {
    fmt.Println(b, a)
}

func exec(f Foo) {
    f.Bar("hello from exec")
}

func main() {
    var test myFoo
    exec(test)
}
```

So in the above, instead of trying to pass in `test.Bar` to `exec`, you would actually define an interface that describes what functionality and then pass in `test` completely.

In the case of filepath.Walk, it does not define an interface and instead expects a function type as an argument. In this case, you would need to wrap your method with a func type `filepath.WalkFunc`

You could probably add an additional method to your type if you find yourself needing to do this alot (not tested)

```
func (t myType) handlerFunc() filepath.WalkFunc {
    return func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        return t.walk(path, info, err)
    }
}
```

Then call `filepath.Walk(".", t.handlerFunc())`